# SQL - CASE WHEN query

Tags: sql, sum, case, having

I am trying to get from my table all invoices raised for those customers who spent more than 1000 over period of last 12 months. Below is my table just for two customers as example:

[image]

And my query:

```
SELECT 
    t.Customer, t.Invoice 
FROM 
    (SELECT
         CI.Customer, CI.Invoice, CI.Date,
         SUM(CASE 
                WHEN CI.Date > DATEADD(month, -12, getdate()) 
                   THEN CI.Valuee 
                ELSE 0 
             END) as Net
     FROM 
         CustomerInvoice CI
     GROUP BY 
         CI.Customer, CISRV.Invoice, CISRV.Date) AS t
GROUP BY 
    t.Customer, t.Invoice
HAVING 
   SUM (t.Net) > 1000
```

As result I will get only invoice INV-341453 but I would like to show also invoices INV-346218 and INV-349065.

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Use ANSI standard window functions:

```
select ci.*
from (select ci.*,
             sum(ci.value) over (partition by ci.customer) as total_value
      from CustomerInvoice CI
      where CI.Date > DATEADD(month, -12, getdate())
     ) ci
where total_value > 1000;
```

By "all invoices", I assume you mean the ones in the past twelve months.

Comment: Thanks Gordon

It works! Very good solution and simple code.

Will learn more about OVER clause..

Answer (score 0):

You could do this by using a grouped query to identify the customers who have gone over the 1000 threshold, and then display all invoices for those customers:

```
SELECT Customer, Invoice 
 FROM CustomerInvoice 
 WHERE Customer IN 
     (SELECT Customer 
     FROM CustomerInvoice
     GROUP BY Customer
     HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN CI.Date>DATEADD(month,-12,getdate()) THEN CI.Valuee ELSE 0 END) > 1000)
```